# Attribute to override generic class based form and use a custom form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have the following form in forms.py:

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['title', 'description'] 
        widgets = {'title': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'description': Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

is there a way I can tell this view (and the `CreateView`)  to use the form above:

```
from .forms import JobForm
    class JobUpdateView(UpdateView):
        model = Job
        fields = ['title', 'description']
        template_name = 'job/edit_job.html'
        form = JobForm() # I imagined some attribute like this to specify the form
```

I'm just getting into using class-cased views and feel like this should have been easy to find with a quick search. Am I missing the point here, are you supposed to not have to define a custom for in forms.py if you are using class-based views?

Comment: you can provide `form_class=JobForm` to your `JobUpdateView`

Comment: @NalinDobhal thanks

Comment: how can I call the form on template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use form_class attribute of UpdateView
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class